# HTML Purifier - Character Encoding

Tags: php, character-encoding, xss, htmlpurifier

I plan on using HTML Purify for the outputs of my webservice. I did not see an integrated "loggin" functionality to check what is replaced, so I wrote it myself.

However, the purifier() function automatically transforms my special character "entities".

For example:

```html
& -> &amp;

&oslash; -> ø
```

The problem is now, that these will also be "logged" as my logging function compares the differences between the "purified" string and the original one. Is there a way to avoid this automatic encoding/decoding, or does anyone have better idea of how to check what is actually replaced?

Thank you!

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The two examples you cite are actually two different use-cases; the one is because HTML Purifier is making your output safe (`& -> &amp;`), the other is HTML Purifier using UTF-8 instead of entities because that's its internal representation.

Generally speaking, if your HTML is safe, HTML Purifier will output semantically equivalent HTML, it's not actually guaranteed to keep e.g. all whitespace or representation, because its focus is entirely on security, not idempotence for safe HTML, and it transforms incoming HTML quite heavily in the interest of thorough analysis.

You *could* force it to always turn all non-ASCII characters into entities with [Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.EscapeNonASCIICharacters), but I doubt that's what you want - it will also change any UTF-8 that's *not* currently an entity into an entity. It also doesn't solve that unescaped HTML special characters will be escaped (`& -> &amp;`) - HTML Purifier doesn't take chances, so even those HTML special characters that are coincidentally/contextually safe will always be encoded.

Instead, take a look at [Core.CollectErrors](http://htmlpurifier.org/live/configdoc/plain.html#Core.CollectErrors). That should enable checking for the changes that you're looking for. Despite the warning in the docs, it is a solid feature. You can see an example usage of that feature [here](https://repo.or.cz/htmlpurifier-web.git/blob/1b3f7f24373ca68f945081dde0d814b824de878f:/demo.php#l182). The tl;dr is that to get the error collector, you use `$purifier->context->get('ErrorCollector');`, and to get your list of errors (which includes replacements), `$errorCollector->getRaw()`. Try that and see if it works?

Comment: Thank you a lot! I will try it out right away. I currently use the PHP function html_entity_decode() to compare both, the original and the purified string and log differences if there are any. This is only for internal Logging, while I just use the purified string for the output. Would you think this is a "good enough" practice? In general, I just want to record what information actually gets deleted and will not be shown in the output of my webservice due to the purifying.

Comment: Since HTML Purifier doesn't really have any guarantees around preserving whitespace, either, I'd really recommend looking into Core.CollectErrors instead. That said, if you're not getting false positives with your current approach, your approach should be fine, as long as you don't ever render it in a web browser without other safeguards (e.g. htmlspecialchars()).